# window.onload isn't working for counter page

Tags: javascript, perl

I'm not understand! Why this code isn't working? window.onload can't double function. How should I this code just?

Perl is alright. But Javascript is per wrong. I need help for Javascript.

**Perl:**

```
print $lqcgi->td({ -class => 'navItemText', -align => 'left'}, '<script> document.write("refresh in <strong><span id=\"counter\"></span></strong> seconds")</script></td></tr>' )

print "<script>document.write('<p><small>You will be redirected to main page in <strong><span id=\"a_reload\"></span></strong> sec.</small></p>')</script>";
```

**Javascript:**

```
   var Time = 60;
    var Counter = zaehler;
    function zaehler(){
        if (Time > 0) {
            Time --;
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Time;
            setTimeout("zaehler()",1000);
        }
        else {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }
    window.onload = Counter;

    function a_confirm(){
        var x = confirm("Are you sure to Confirmation?");
        if (x == true){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    var Time_2 = 5;
    var Counter_2 = c_reload
    function c_reload(){
        if (Time_2 > 0) {
            Time_2 --;
            document.getElementById('a_reload').innerHTML = Time_2;
            setTimeout("c_reload()", 1000);
        }
        else{
            window.history.back(-1);
        }
    }
    window.onload = Counter_2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Counter = function (){
```

should solve your problem. Currently you're assigning a reference (*zaehler*) before creating it. Would be

```
my $Counter = $zaehler;
my $zaehler = sub {
...
```

in Perl.

Comment: Thank you. `var Counter = function(){}` is working, but for `var Counter_2=function(){}` isn't working. Why is that a problem?

Comment: I found something code. 

`var Time = 60;
var Counter = function(){
 if (Time > 0) {
  Time --;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Time;
 }
 else {
  window.location.reload(true);
 }
}
var myVar = window.setInterval("Counter()", 1000);`

`var Time_2 = 10;
window.onload = function(){
 if (Time_2 > 0) {
  Time_2 --;
  document.getElementById('a_reload').innerHTML = Time_2;
  setTimeout('window.onload()', 1000);
 }
 else{
  window.history.back(-1);
 }
}
window.onload = Counter_2;`

That's very much better. But thank you very much.